# Drush update for the first time hosed my website

Tags: commerce, drush, database

Running latest versions of Drupal, etc.
Localhost - dev site
Maintenance mode

While trying to install Commerce_kickstart and running Drush for first time to update modules,  Drupal got completely hosed.

Can not find problem in database
Repaired all databases but get Drupal white screen, no error messages
Phpmyadmin won't work

Can anyone offer a series of steps to attempt recovery or at least find out what went wrong?

Thanks in advance.  I need ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the updates of your modules is messing up. Most recently I had this problem with updating Rules which broke my site the same way it did yours (WSOD).

Reverting and updating one by one can show you what went wrong.

If you use drush you can do: drush up modulename (e.g. drush up rules) to update one by one, instead of drush up which updates everything. drush up drupal only updates core.